# Restricting access to a video file on the network

Tags: security, permissions, file-sharing

I have an MP4 file on our Windows 2008R2 fileserver that I want people to be able to view, but not to create copies of.  Is there a security permission configuration that would allow this?

Comment: This is like saying "I want people to see my website, but they're not allowed to save the text."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in Windows. When you grant user "Read" permission, then copying is possible. You can always enable Folders/Files auditing and review log to check who copied data and when to track this issue.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there can be no permissions that would permit a user from viewing the file and at the same time prevent that user from copying the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what DRM is for. Whether you can effectively wrap MP4 into a DRM scheme, I have no idea - now you have the terminology to allow you to try yourself! Remember how effective most DRM schemes are, though.